# How to display this content in a line?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display this content in a line so that it shows with Shopping on the left of my page and content in the "right" div on the right. I have tried floating the div to the right but that didn't work.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
<header>
    <h1>Shopping</h1>
    <div id="cart"
        <a href="#"><img src="images/cart.png" width="80" height="80"></a>
        <p> Cart: 0 </p>
        <a href="#">Login</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WByNH.png)

Comment: Also worth noting is that you're missing a closing angle brace on your opening `div` tag.

Comment: Show your CSS, show what you tried exactly.

Comment: How do you wanna do it? Do you have a pic of it?

Answer (score 0):

`<h1>` and `<div>` are `block` element so they take a whole line each. You have to make them as below to display them in a line.

```
header h1, header #cart {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Well there're a few more methods to show them in a line, but this is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/g6camng3/1/

HTML

```
<header>
<h1>Shopping</h1>
<div id="right">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="80" height="80"></a>
    <p> Cart: 0 </p>
    <a href="#">Login</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
h1 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

#right {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `span` instead of `p` tag :

```
<header>
    <h1>Shopping</h1>
    <div id="cart"
        <span><a href="#"><img src="images/cart.png" width="80" height="80"></a></span><span> Cart: 0 </span><span><a href="#">Login</a></span>
    </div>
</header>
```